# Items on left to be added in the box on the right upon clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items placed on the left (itemDrop) and would like to add it in the box on the right (itemList) when selected. Terms: unable to select the same item, unable to select more than 3 items. Can only edit javascript file, HTML file untouchable.

HTML:

```
<div id="itemSelectHeader"> <H2>Item List</H2>
<div id="itemSelect">SELECT FROM HERE
<div id="itemDrop" class="itemSetup">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="itemListSection">
    <H3>Items Selected</H3>
    <div id="itemList" class="itemSetup"> <ul></ul></div>
</div>
```

Add ons:
- clear box when clear button clicked
- submit only when there are 3 items selected

```
    <div id="itemBtn">
         <button type="button" id="clearItem">CLEAR ALL</button>
         <button type="button" id="selectItem">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
```

tried the following for clear button but it doesn't work. But worked for alert

```
    $("#clearItem").click(function(){
        //alert("try");
        $("#itemList").reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will serve your terms.
`Terms: unable to select the same item, unable to select more than 3 items. Can only edit javascript file`

```js
    let counter = 0;
let selectedItem = [];
let drop = document.querySelector("#itemList ul");
let lists = document.querySelectorAll("#itemDrop ul li");
for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
     lists[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        appendPlace(i, lists[i]);
     });
}

function appendPlace(itemNo, item) {
 if(!selectedItem[itemNo] && counter < 3)
 {
  let x = document.createElement("LI");
    let t = document.createTextNode(item.innerHTML);
    x.appendChild(t);
  drop.appendChild(x);
  selectedItem[itemNo] = 1;
  counter++;
 }
}
```

Comment: but because my items have different names (eg. abc, def, ghi...) how I can implement the code so that the selected ones shown in the box on the right side would be the exact name I selected from the left instead of item 1, item 2, etc?

Comment: I have also added buttons in, Hope you can help with that too

Comment: use `remove` method instead reset

Comment: it did clear up but then I can't add any more items once I have selected 3, even after I cleared the box

Answer (score 1):

You can get lists in html by tag selector and then add an click event listener to first list for appending childs to second list.

Look at the following:

```js
let lists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

lists[0].addEventListener("click",function(e) {         
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI" && lists[1].childElementCount<3) {           
            lists[1].appendChild(e.target)
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="itemSelectHeader"> 
<H2>Item List</H2>
<div id="itemSelect">SELECT FROM HERE
<div id="itemDrop" class="itemSetup">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="itemListSection">
    <H3>Items Selected</H3>
    <div id="itemList" class="itemSetup"> <ul></ul></div>
</div>
```